# Как установить значение для закрытого поля при помощи автоматических свойств в C#

Tags: c#

```
class Person{
    private static int age { get; set; }
}

 class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person.age = 10;//так не работает
    }        
}
```

Но вот так можно добраться до закрытого свойства:

```
 class Person
{
    private static int age;
    public static int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return age;
        }
        set
        {
            age = value;
        }
    }
}

 class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person.Age = 10;
    }        
}
```

Comment: `age = 20`? уточните вопрос, покажите пример кода, где не работает, а хотелось бы чтобы работало. Какое поведение ожидается?

Comment: @aepot разбираю теорию и не могу понять работу автоматических свойств в данном случае. С закрытым полем применяя неавтоматические свойства все понятно. При помощи аксессоров можно прописать явно присвоение и получение значений закрытого поля.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @aepot в вашем дополнении описывается то, о чем я говорил - что скрывает обычный геттер и сеттер - это "понятно"

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю вашего вопроса. Чтобы был доступ к свойству за пределами класса, оно должно быть публичным. Точка. Смысл автосвойства в том, что можно применять модификаторы доступа дополнительно отдельно к геттеру и сеттеру.

Comment: Наверное, дошло. Все дело в модификаторе `private static int age { get; set; }`. Получается, что здесь свойства тоже под модификатором private. В этом и суть.

Comment: @aepot спасибо за возможность обсуждения - разобрался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте свойство публичным

```cs
class Person
{
    public static int age { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
Person.age = 10; // так работает
```

---

Если вам "все понятно" с обычными свойствами, то вот так выглядит ваше автосвойство после обработки компилятором.

```cs
internal class Person
{
    private static int <age>k__BackingField;

    private static int age
    {
        get
        {
            return <age>k__BackingField;
        }
        set
        {
            <age>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: с публичным свойством все понятно. А как быть с закрытым свойством?

Comment: @Proshka закрытым с какой целью? Чтобы не изменять его извне? Если разработчик решил не изменять свойство извне, значит его не стоит изменять? А если надо изменить, то почему бы просто не сделать его публичным?

Comment: @Proshka есть такая фишка свойства, которой нет у поля, напрмер вы можете сделать так, что свойство внутри можно читать и писать, а снаружи только читать. `public static int age { get; private set; }` ну или наоборот можно, но я таких случаев не встречал.

Comment: хорошо, зачем тогда существуют закрытые поля, доступ к которым осуществляется при помощи свойств? Поля, насколько я понимаю, говорят о состоянии, а методы - о поведении. Допустим, мне нужно инициализировать закрытое поле и я могу это сделать при помощи сеттера. Или я что-то не так понимаю.

Comment: @Proshka если вы хотите инициализировать автосвойство прямо в конструкторе, и потом его никогда не изменять, то можете использовать просто `{ get; }`, в этом случае поведение будет похоже на `readonly` поле.

Comment: про конструктор речь сейчас не идет. Сеттер скрывает в себе такой код: age = value; Вот я и хочу понять, почему в автоматическом свойстве это не работает в приведенном выше случае

Comment: @Proshka какая разница, что скрывает сеттер, если у вас не доступа к этому сеттеру? Автосвойство работает точно так же как и обычное свойство с явным сеттером. Если вы сделаете свойство приватным. вы не сможете ему ничего присвоить. Сделайте обычное свойство приватным и получите тот же самый эффект.